# How to access local files on a namenode in Java?

Tags: java, hadoop, hdfs

My `var/log/hadoop-hdfs/hdfs-audit.log` is located locally on a namenode and is accessed by `head /var/log/hadoop-hdfs/hdfs-audit.log`. My data files are accessed by `hdfs dfs -ls /` whereas the audit files can be cd'ed into. Right now I can access my hdfs files in java but every time I try `fs.getLocal(conf)` where `conf` is set by `conf.set(FileSystem.FS_DEFAULT_NAME_KEY, namenode)`, I get local files on my computer, not the local files on the namenode.

The following works to get all files and directories under data.

```
public class HdfsAuditLogParser {
    private final String cluster;
    private final FileSystem fs;

    public HdfsAuditLogParser(String cluster, String namenode) throws IOException {
        this.cluster = cluster;
        Configuration conf = new Configuration();
        conf.set(FileSystem.FS_DEFAULT_NAME_KEY, namenode);
        this.fs = FileSystem.get(conf);
    }

    public String parse() throws IOException {
        for (FileStatus f : fs.listStatus(new Path("/data/"))){
            System.out.println(f.getPath().toString());
        }
        return "output";
    }
}
```

But if I change /data/ to /var/log/, it doesn't not work, I even tried switching `this.fs = FileSystem.getLocal(conf);` but that doesn't work—that just gives me the files under var/log/ in my computer not the files in the namenode.

In short, I would like to access the hdfs-audit.log file through java, the same way I can access the hdfs databases and tables and other files in hdfs. Is there any way to do that.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing special about a Namenode here. Even if possible, this means any file on the system would be readable over the network, which is insecure.

In short, you can't access local files without running your script locally to that machine. Even adjusting your configurations would make you able to only read HDFS data, not files local to any particular namenode or datanode

If you really need to read a remote file, you could use JSch then `cat` the file content over an SSH connection from Java. Or you could run a service on the namenode that exposes your specific logs over a web server rather than exposing the entire filesystem